# Как загрузить grub2 через pxe?

Tags: linux, grub, pxe

Есть ли способ подгрузить на машину *grub2* через *pxe*, по типу того, как подгружается *pxelinux*?

Comment: да, есть, конечно. google:"grub2 pxe".

Comment: А зачем именно это понадобилось?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Необходимо создать загрузочный образ grub2 для pxe. Пример:

```
    grub-mkimage -c grub.cfg -d /usr/local/lib/grub/i386-pc --format=i386-pc-pxe \
    -o /tftpboot/grub.pxe pxe pxechain tftp http net \
    part_bsd part_gpt part_msdos boot biosdisk ext2 xfs lvm drivemap \
    gzio xzio lzopio cpio \
    loopback linux iso9660 udf memdisk chain \
    minicmd extcmd \
    ahci ehci ohci uhci \
    acpi lsacpi pci setpci reboot halt \
    help echo gfxmenu gfxterm font date configfile ls search vga vbe png video videoinfo loadenv
```

grub.cfg - файл конфигурации загрузчика

Настройка DHCP и tftpd стандартно для любой аналогичной PXE загрузки